# How to stream out video from iphone?

Tags: iphone, html, flash, stream

I want to make an application to stream out a UIVIEW. So it can be watch from a webplayer for example Flash or HTML 5. But I am really lost how to start. Any Idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also been working on such a project recently and I found the help of these websites very useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/, http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera, or https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

It can be done via HTML5 and Javascript and it's relatively easy to do.

Hope they help!

EDIT: Maybe I misinterpreted your question. Do you want to stream the camera from the iPhone, or do you want to stream the screen of the iPhone?